# Let X and Y be i.i.d. Expo(λ), calculate $T=\log(X/Y)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Expo(λ), and $T = \log(X/Y )$. Find the CDF and PDF of $T$.

$P(T \le t)=P \left(\log(\frac XY) \le t\right)=P(X \le 10^tY)$

\begin{align}
P(T \le t) & = P(X \le 10^tY)=P(X \le 10^tY \mid Y=y)P(Y=y) \\[10pt]
& =(1-e^{λ10^ty})λe^{-λy} = λe^{-λy}-λe^{-λy(10^{ty}+1)}
\end{align}

$$f(t)=-λ^2e^{-λy}-λ^2(10^{ty}+1)e^{-λy(10^{ty}+1)}; \quad y \ge 0$$

Is it wrong?

Comment: I wondered how the number $10$ gets involved. Then I remembered that some people construe "$\log$" as meaning $\log_{10}.$ But almost certainly, whoever wrote this intended $\log_e. \qquad$

Comment: $P(Y=y)$ is zero, so that can't be right when you write the CDF of $T$. This should be replaced with the density of $Y$, and you have to integrate the entire expression over $y$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks